# Why does calling create as a class method not save the record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose a simple ActiveRecord model corresponding to a table with just two columns, `id` and `name`:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.my_create(name)
    create(:name => name)
  end
end
```

If I call `Model.my_create`, a record is created and saved:

```
>> Model.my_create('foo')
=> #<Model id: 1, name: "foo">
```

But If I call `Model.create` straight, the record is **not** saved:

```
>> Model.create(:name => 'bar')
=> #<Model id: nil, name: "bar">
```

How come calling create in a class method has different behaviour than calling it straight *as* a class method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Model.create(...)` works fine for me.

It's probably worth using `Model.create!` which will raise an exception if there's a validation error which is probably the cause of the record not being saved or you could check the `errors` on the returned instance. I've been bitten by `Model.create` before because it leaves it up to you to check whether the object was saved or not and for what reason.